# Bind variables in PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using below code to execute `MySQL` query in `PHP`.

```
$cus_id = '1';
$query = new QUERY();
$clause = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE cus_id=:cus_id AND status='ACTIVE'";
$params = array('cus_id'=>$cus_id);
$result = $query->run($clause, $params)->fetchAll();
```

Now the question is: is it secure enough. Or do I need to bind the static String as well? Something like:

```
$clause = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE cus_id=:cus_id AND status=:status";
$params = array('cus_id'=>$cus_id, 'status'=>'ACTIVE');
```

Comment: You need to learn about [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Because your question is suggestive of cargo-cult programming - doing something without ever understanding WHY you're doing it.

Comment: Thank you everyone. @MarcB: I read your article before. I though I should clear it once again.

Answer (score 1):

It's secure because `ACTIVE` isn't user input. So you don't need to bind it.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine the way you have it.  The value for `status` isn't being dynamically assembled and doesn't create any vulnerabilities.